# Derive A Second Order Differential Equation for i1 - Circuits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

The equations are:

$$
\begin{cases}
I_2 R +\dfrac{Q}{C} = V \\
L \dfrac{dI_1}{dt} = I_2 R \\
\dfrac{dQ}{dt} = I_1 + I_2 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: @Isham I can't figure out how to get it in terms of I1

Comment: Find $Q$ in the first and substitute in the third. Then find $I_2$ from the second, and substitute in the modified third.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from here:
$$
\begin{cases}
I_2 R =-\dfrac{Q}{C} +V \\
L \dfrac{dI_1}{dt} = I_2 R \\
\dfrac{dQ}{dt} = I_1 + I_2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Substitute $I_2$ in the last two equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
I_2 R =-\dfrac{Q}{C} +V \\
L \dfrac{dI_1}{dt} = -\dfrac{Q}{C} +V \\
R\dfrac{dQ}{dt} = RI_1  -\dfrac{Q}{C} +V \\
\end{cases}
$$

$$L \dfrac{dI_1}{dt} = -\dfrac{Q}{C} +V \\$$
Differentiate:
$$L \dfrac{d^2I_1}{dt^2} = -\dfrac 1 C\dfrac{dQ}{dt}  \\$$
$$RL \dfrac{d^2I_1}{dt^2} = -\dfrac 1 C(RI_1  -\dfrac{Q}{C} +V )\\$$
$$L \dfrac{dI_1}{dt} = -\dfrac{Q}{C} +V \\$$
$$\implies   -\dfrac{Q}{C} =L \dfrac{dI_1}{dt}-V  \\$$
Therefore:
$$\boxed {RLC \dfrac{d^2I_1}{dt^2}+ L \dfrac{dI_1}{dt}+RI_1 =0}$$
I hope that's what you wanted a differential with $I_1$ as the function.